# MMA7361 Accelerometer Always Displays Same Values

Tags: arduino, sensors, accelerometer

I recently purchased a 3-axis accelerometer from Amazon, and can't seem to find how it works. I've been looking for quite a while now, and haven't found any real clues. The x, y, and z values always seem to return the same values. They change when I tilt or move the accelerometer, but revert to about 120 for each reading. I am currently using this device with the Arduino Uno, using the following code:

```
int x=1,y=2,z=3;
void setup() {
  pinMode(x, INPUT);
  pinMode(y, INPUT);
  pinMode(z, INPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
 Serial.println();
 Serial.print(analogRead(x));
 Serial.print(", ");
 Serial.print(analogRead(y));
 Serial.print(", ");
 Serial.print(analogRead(z));
}
```

Also, how would I go about converting this to tilt?

Comment: I copy your code inline to combat link rot.

Also, I notice on the Amazon postings that there is Arduino code available for this device. Have you tried it?

Comment: I didn't find any... Could you possibly link me to it?

Comment: A quick Google seems to bring up a number of examples: [Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/mma7361-library/), [Arduino Forum](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=38132.0), [DFRobot Example](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Triple_Axis_Accelerometer_MMA7361_%28SKU:_DFR0143%29), [GE Tech Wiki](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/MMA7361_Triple_Axis_Accelerometer_Breakout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project on Google Code called [MMA7361-library](http://code.google.com/p/mma7361-library/). The [GE Tech Wiki](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/MMA7361_Triple_Axis_Accelerometer_Breakout) has a simple example showing how to use this library. Copied inline below for posterity.

```
#include <AcceleroMMA7361.h>
AcceleroMMA7361 accelero;
int x;
int y;
int z;
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 accelero.begin(13, 12, 11, 10, A0, A1, A2);
 accelero.setARefVoltage(5); //sets the AREF voltage to 3.3V
 accelero.setSensitivity(LOW); //sets the sensitivity to +/-6G
 accelero.calibrate();
}
void loop()
{
 x = accelero.getXAccel();
 y = accelero.getYAccel();
 z = accelero.getZAccel();
 Serial.print("\nx: ");
 Serial.print(x);
 Serial.print(" \ty: ");
 Serial.print(y);
 Serial.print(" \tz: ");
 Serial.print(z);
 Serial.print("\tG*10^-2");
 delay(500); //make it readable
}
```